# validate update form

Tags: php, javascript, validation

I am creating a page in which I am fetching data from table and showing data in textbox to allow user to update record. I also validate the user input to textbox. But the problem is when the user does not change any field and click on submit, it validates username field i.e. it always wants to change (or edit textbox) the value of textboxes.

Here is my code:

```
<?php
include("conn.php");
$id=$_GET['id'];
$sql="SELECT * FROM test WHERE id='$id'";
$res=mysql_query($sql);
$row=mysql_fetch_array($res);
?>

<script type='text/javascript'>
function formValidator()
{
    // Make quick references to our fields
    alert("hiiiiiii");
    var name = document.getElementById('name').value;
    var email = document.getElementById('emailid').value;
    var ph = document.getElementById('ph').value;

    if( name=="" || name==null)
     {
         alert("Please Enter user name");
         return false;
     }
     var alphaExp = /^[a-zA-Z]+$/;
     if(!name.match(alphaExp))
      {
          alert("please Enter only Alphabates for Name");
          return false;
      }

      if(email=="" || email=="null")
      {
          alert("Please Enter Email Address");
          return false;
      }
      var emailExp = /^[\w\-\.\+]+\@[a-zA-Z0-9\.\-]+\.[a-zA-z0-9]{2,4}$/;
      if(!email.match(emailExp))
       {
           alert("please Enter valide email address");
            return false;
       }
       if(ph=="" || ph=="null")
       {
           alert("Please Enter Phone Number");
           return false;
       }
       var numericExpression = /^[0-9]+$/;
       if(!ph.match(numericExpression))
       {
           alert("Enter only Digit for Phone Number");
           return false;
       }
}
</script>


<form name="updateform" method="POST" action="update_ind_new.php" onsubmit='return formValidator()'>
  <table width="200" border="0">
    <tr>
     <td>User Name</td>
      <td>E-Mail</td>
       <td>phno</td>
     </tr>
    <tr>
    <td><label>
        <input name="name" type="text" id="name" value=" <?php echo $row['name']; ?>" >
      </label></td>
      <td><label>
        <input name="email" type="text" id="emailid" value=" <?php echo $row['emailid']; ?>" >
      </label></td>
      <td><label>

        <input name="ph" type="text" id="ph" value=" <?php echo $row['phno']; ?>" >
      </label></td>

    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td> <input name="id" type="hidden" id="id" value=" <?php echo $row['id']; ?>"></td>
      <td><label>
        <input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit">
      </label></td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</form>
```

Comment: Well if your values are coming from DB so they must have passed the validations to get in there.So There should not be a problem in re validating them.

Comment: Did you check the values of your inputs with Firebug?

Comment: I am not clear understand your problem, but why you put space before all value value=" <?php echo $row['name']; ?>" >. Name with space not valid according formValidator()

Comment: Apply the same validation function that you have given for the add input in your add form

Comment: @techie_28:i have apply validation on insert page but if user want to update the mobile/phone number and by mistakly if they forget to add some digit then it will insert wrong mobile number into  table.

Comment: @NikolajBorisik: Not problem with value syntax. problem is if user choose to update his data then i will show the user data to the textbox to edit there data but if user change only phone number my code always want to change all fileds.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

write `return true;` at the end of this line

```
   if(!ph.match(numericExpression))
   {
       alert("Enter only Digit for Phone Number");
       return false;
   }
   return true;
```

Answer (score 1):

Put `return true;` at the end of all the conditions in the validation function

or put a validations in "if else if else" conditions